# Lookup and Replace Entire Row

Tags: excel

I put together a fantasy sports pool and am looking to have a master-list of players (and relevant statistics) and have the statistics auto-populate for the players on each of the teams.

So when I update Guy's stats in one row, it autofills the stats row for every team that selected Guy.

So when I fill in here: http://cl.ly/image/0U0E2J382s2i

It populates here (among other places): http://cl.ly/image/1l1z3V3q1u27

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Index/Match functions for joining data from one table to another. Google Index/Match for code examples.